$\mathbb{C}$-linear combination of sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$.
I am wondering the following statement is true or false:
Let $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ be sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ with $a(n) \ne b(n)$ for all $n$. Suppose that  $c(n):= \alpha a(n)+\beta b(n)$ with $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $\exists m$ s.t. $c(m) \ne 0$. If $c(n) \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$, then $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Q}.$
I tried to use the fact that the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, but in fact, I don't think this is not a good approach since the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a subspace over $\mathbb{C}$..
How can I prove or disprove it ?? Any idea will be helpful to me. Thanks for your help!

This false. For example, one could have $a(n) = 0$ and $b(n) \neq 0$ for all $n$. Then any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\beta = 1$ satisfies the requirements, but $\alpha$ needs not be rational.

Thanks for your comment. Do you have any counter examples for the case $a(n), b(n)$ are nontrivial sequences ?

$a(n) = 1$, $b(n) = 2$ for all $n$, $\alpha = 1 - 2\pi$ and $\beta = \pi$. ($\pi$ can, of course, be replaced by any other irrational number.) (If you want non-constant sequences change to $a(n) = n$ and $b(n) = 2n$.)

Thanks a lot. You save me twice :)
